# an error occurred while installing one of the file systems. for more information, run the command "dmesg"

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a problem with the wsl system. Namely, I have windows 11 on my laptop and I installed wsl. When I launched it after installing it, I got this message

```
the windows subsystem for linux optional component is not enabled. please enable it and try again.
```

I have enabled wsl options in Windows features in the control panel. I restarted the computer and after starting wsl a message appeared that the kernel needs to be updated to wsl2. I did it following the guide on this page https://pstrozniak.com/aktualizacja-do-wsl-2/. I also downloaded this file https://docs.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package and clicked on it to update . Everything went smoothly, I restarted the computer, started wsl and this message appeared from the koei

```
an error occurred while installing one of the file systems. for more information, run the command "dmesg".
```

I wanted to get rid of it but didn't know how (I'm a beginner in Linux). I ran sudo apt update, sudo apt upgrade, and it worked. How is this possible? What could have caused this message. I will be grateful for any help

Comment: Are you sure about the message?  Could it have been `An error occurred mounting one of your file systems.`?

Comment: I'm sure. I got this message. But I typed sudo apt update, then sudo apt upgrade, and it works. Why? What could be causing this error?

Comment: It's really hard to say since you are literally the [only person in the world](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22an%20error%20occurred%20while%20installing%20one%20of%20the%20file%20systems%22) (or at least on the web that Google has indexed) who has ever had that message, at least so far ;-).  That's why I'm thinking it was the ["mounting"](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5456) error message that you got.  If it's a different error, then it's likely you've mistyped it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can check default distro

```
wsl --list
```

You will get something like below

Windows Subsystem forLinux Distributions:

docker-desktop
docker-desktop-data (Default)

If "docker-desktop-data" is the default then you can change the default to "docker-desktop" by executing this command

```
wsl -s docker-desktop
```